# nested_form not saving to model Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms, model-associations

I think I am on the right path for the following, though i cannot save the form data to the model. I have 2 models

```
class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :home_score, :away_score, :fixtures_attributes

  has_many :fixtures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fixtures
end

class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :fixture_date, :kickoff_time

  belongs_to :predictions
end
```

To create a new prediction record i have a form that takes all the fixtures and pre populates the form and the user will just add scores next to each team

```
<%= form_for @prediction do |f| %>
<!-- Gets all fixtures -->
<%= f.fields_for :fixtures, @fixtures<!-- grabs as a collection --> do |ff| %>

<%= ff.text_field :home_team %> VS <%= ff.text_field :away_team %><%= f.text_field :home_score %><%= f.text_field :away_score %><br>

<% end %>
<%= f.submit 'Submit Predictions' %>
<% end %>
```

Then i have my controller to take care of the new/create action, which i think is where i may be falling over

```
class PredictionsController < ApplicationController

def new
 @prediction = Prediction.new
 @prediction.fixtures.build
 @fixtures = Fixture.all
end

 def create
  @prediction = Prediction.new(params[:prediction])
  @prediction.save
   if @prediction.save
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Predictions Submitted Successfully'
   else
    render 'new'
end
  end
 end
```

and finally my routes

```
resources :predictions
resources :fixtures
```

So when i submit the form i get the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PredictionsController#create
Couldn't find Fixture with ID=84 for Prediction with ID=
```

Looking at the params being parsed (snapshot below), something does not look right, for one the home_score and away_score are not being passed through.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"DfeEWlTde7deg48/2gji7zSHJ19MOGcMTxEsQEKdVsQ=",
  "prediction"=>{"fixtures_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"home_team"=>"Arsenal",
 "away_team"=>"Norwich",
 "id"=>"84"},
 "1"=>{"home_team"=>"Aston Villa",
 "away_team"=>"Fulham",
 "id"=>"85"},
 "2"=>{"home_team"=>"Everton",
 "away_team"=>"QPR",
 "id"=>"86"}
```

Current Output of form

[image]

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

Comment: check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `@fixtures` to `Fixture.all` in the new method in your prediction controller, you are including every fixture, not just the fixtures belonging to your prediction. When the results of the form are passed to the create controller there are fixtures associated with other predictions being passed in which is the source of the error you have reported. Perhaps you want something like `@fixtures = @prediction.fixtures`.

What you are doing in the `fields_for` block also looks fairly wrong to my eyes. You are using `f.text_field` for your `home_score` and `away_score` inputs. This will repeat the same form element for the prediction model in each fixture field. You won't get the result you want from this. To be honest, I'm struggling to understand how this association makes sense. Are you able to explain it a little better? My suspicion is that your models are not quite set up the way you need them to be.

edit:

OK, I think I have a better idea of what you're trying to achieve now. You're trying to create many predictions in one form and prefill the home_team and away_team from a list of existing fixtures, right?

Okay, assuming that is so, you're definitely approaching it the wrong way. You don't need a many-to-one relationship between your prediction and fixture models (as you have correctly surmised). What you need to do is generate your form by iterating over the collection of fixtures and populating the `home_team` and `away_team` fields from the current fixture instance. Do you actually need these to be editable text fields, or are you just putting them in a text field so they get passed through? If so, you could use hidden fields instead.

The problem now though, is that Rails doesn't easily allow creating multiple records in the one form. It's not something I've done before and it would take me quite a bit of trial-and-error to make it work, but here's a best guess for one way of making it so.

```
models

class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :home_score, :away_score, :fixtures_attributes
end

class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :fixture_date, :kickoff_time
end
```

---

```
controller

class PredictionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @prediction = Prediction.new
    @fixtures = Fixture.all
  end

  def create
    begin
      params[:predictions].each do |prediction|
        Prediction.new(prediction).save!
      end
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Predictions Submitted Successfully'
    rescue
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
view

<%= form_tag controller: 'predictions', action: 'create', method: 'post' do %>
  <% @fixtures.each do |fixture| %>
    <%= fixture.home_team %> vs <%= fixture.away_team %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][home_team]", fixture.home_team %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][away_team]", fixture.away_team %>
    <%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "predictions[][away_score]" %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit predictions" %>
<% end %>
```

So essentially I'm creating a form that returns an array of parameters. I can't use the model form helpers in this situation.

One way around this would be to create a dummy model that has_many predictions and create a nested form using this.

Anyway, that's a lot of untested code that may never get looked at so I'm going to leave it there for now.

Comment: Hi @brad, I have updated question with image of current output. My first thoughts where maybe I didnt need an association as all i want to be able to do with the data in the fixtures model is populate the form with fixtures and then create a prediction record with its attributes. What are your thoughts on that? after a prediction record has been created there shouldnt be any relationship to the fixture model should there?

Comment: thanks brad, i will take a look and let you know how i get on, i always try things so it would never not get looked at :)

Comment: ok so at the moment the form is blank and no fixtures or fields for the score are showing

Comment: ah the form tag was missing =, this came in rails 3 > i believe, forgot about that and i see what you are doing with the hidden fields, much better :) all params are being passed into the prediction model aswell..

Comment: I have to say @brad, the more i look at this and understand it, it really is a very nice solution, very clean

Comment: Glad you liked it - I'm surprised it works without me being able to test the code. I've fixed the missing =. There is one slightly dirty thing about this solution though; I've used the existing routes and create method to create multiple records which is not strictly what they are for. It should use either a separate create_multiple method, or maybe even better a create method in a MultiplePredictions controller. You would have to change your routing and form to cope with this.

Comment: The other problem with my create method is that if one of the predictions fails validation, all of the previous predictions will have been saved prior to the exception being triggered and rescued. You should really wrap this mass-assignment of predictions in a transaction.

Comment: A lot of stuff with complex forms is abstracted away by Rails, which is great most of the time, but when you step off the beaten path you have to learn a bit more about what's going on. If you ever do have to create an actual nested form I highly recommend using the nested_form gem or something similar. For more information about how I've named the form fields to generate the necessary parameters, look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions (you've probably already found this if you've been reading around the topic).

Comment: Another thought! I don't know if it would matter for your app, but the values in the hidden fields(fixture.home_team and fixture.away_team) could easily be changed by a user. If this does matter then you need a better way to pass this information around.

Comment: Good point, i will have some basic validation, but do you have any suggestions to pass that info?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing more about your app. Perhaps pass a unique slug through each line of the form identifying the fixture?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't spent a lot of time looking because my wife is making me leave soon.  But if I understand things right each of your rows in your view is from fixtures and predictions model association.  The params hash you are getting is a mess because default behavior is going to be a view that is updating a single record ID.  So you are bringing multiple records into a single view and trying to update multiple records at once.

Your create method in your model

```
@prediction = Prediction.new(params[:prediction])
```

But your params hash being passed is this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"DfeEWlTde7deg48/2gji7zSHJ19MOGcMTxEsQEKdVsQ=",
  "prediction"=>{"fixtures_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"home_team"=>"Arsenal",
 "away_team"=>"Norwich",
 "id"=>"84"},
 "1"=>{"home_team"=>"Aston Villa",
 "away_team"=>"Fulham",
 "id"=>"85"},
 "2"=>{"home_team"=>"Everton",
 "away_team"=>"QPR",
 "id"=>"86"}
```

So you have to get more logic in your create method in your predictions controller to iterate through the hash you are receiving and save each row one at a time.