# Using non associated models data in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, form-for

Is it possible to access another models attributes without having associations? For example I want to create a Prediciton record via a form using the fixture models attributes

```
<%= form_for @prediction do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :fixtures, @fixtures do |builder| %>

<%= builder.text_field :home_team %> VS <%= builder.text_field :away_team %><%= f.text_field :home_score %><%= f.text_field :away_score %><br>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

how would i get the attributes of the fixture model without associating the two models?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier if you create the association.  If you are not going to create the association, such in the case where you are using a view not backed by a model and your are pulling in and modifying various models from it (assumption I am making) you can do something similar to this:

First make sure you setup routes.rb for whichever methods you are planning to use against the various models.

predictions model

```
@fixtures = Fixture.all
```

or specific attributes example

```
@fixtures = Fixture.select([:home_team, :away_team, :home_score, :away_score]).all
```

The above is if you are updating another models records.  You will also need to modify the create method.

Your view you would want to change from a form_for to a form_tag:

```
form_tag('/predictions') do
```

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: hi, many thanks for your answer, what i am trying to achieve is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987743/nested-form-not-saving-to-model-rails-3 , would really appreciate it if you could perhaps take a look, im hitting my head against a brick wall at the moment

Comment: I'll go over there and take a look.